# Capture output in Azure Data Factory WebActivity

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a Pipeline that invokes an API endpoint using WebActivity to start a long-running job.
As per specification, the API starts the job in the background and returns `HTTP Status Code 202` along with a json object like this:

```
{
    "TransactionID": "534b1867-a5ac-41b3-9a57-xxx",
    "TransactionStatus": "Processing"
}
```

Then the Pipeline waits until the status of that `TransactionID` changed to `Completed` using a combo of another `WebActivity` and `WaitActivity` in a `Loop` activity.

This pipeline **was working correctly until today (June, 29th 2020)** but now the json output of the WebActivity is not captured anymore by ADF.
*Before anyone asks: we have not changed anything in the Pipeline or in the API itself, it just stopped working.*

My question is: why Azure Data Factory is not capturing anymore the output of web activities when the status code is not `200`? Were we doing somethign wrong and now Azure fixed it or has Azure changed the behaviour of WebActivity without notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not surprisingly, Azure Data Factory changed behavior today (June 30) and all pipelines started working again.

If you came here to see a solution, there isn't any. It solved by itself.

I will keep this post in case it happens again so we can discuss and update accordingly.